# Induction on Menger's theorem by Diestel in Graph Theory

Tags: graph-theory

How does exactly the induction go in the proof number one? What is the  induction hypothesis there and what is the induction step?

> By the induction hypothesis, $G/e$ contains an $A–B$ separator $Y$ of
>   fewer than $k$ vertices.

Whole theorem and proof is [here](http://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/diestel/books/graph.theory/preview/Ch3.pdf), page 67.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As it says at the beginning of the proof, the induction is on $\|G\|$, the number of edges of $G$. The induction hypothesis is that Menger’s theorem is true for all graphs with fewer edges than $G$.

The proof then proceeds by contradiction. Suppose that $k$ is the minimum number of vertices separating $A$ and $B$ in $G$, but, contrary to Menger’s theorem, $G$ does not have $k$ disjoint $A$-$B$ paths. We’re assuming at this point that $\|G\|\ge 1$, so $G$ has an edge $e=xy$. Let $v_e$ be the contraction vertex in $G/e$, and set

$$A'=\begin{cases}
A,&\text{if }A\cap\{x,y\}=\varnothing\\
\big(A\setminus\{x,y\}\big)\cup\{v_e\},&\text{if }A\cap\{x,y\}\ne\varnothing
\end{cases}$$

and

$$B\,'=\begin{cases}
B,&\text{if }B\cap\{x,y\}=\varnothing\\
\big(B\setminus\{x,y\}\big)\cup\{v_e\},&\text{if }B\cap\{x,y\}\ne\varnothing\;.
\end{cases}$$

An $A'$-$B\,'$ path in $G/e$ that does not contain $v_e$ is an $A$-$B$ path in $G$, and an $A'$-$B\,'$ path in $G/e$ that does contain $v_e$ induces an $A$-$B$ path in $G$ in an obvious way. Moreover, it’s clear that disjoint $A'$-$B\,'$ paths in $G/e$ correspond to disjoint $A$-$B$ paths in $G$, so $G/e$ must have fewer than $k$ disjoint $A'$-$B\,'$ paths. Since $\|G/e\|=\|G\|-1<\|G\|$, the conclusion of Menger’s theorem hold for $G/e$ by the induction hypothesis, so $G/e$ has an $A'$-$B\,'$ separator $Y$ with fewer than $k$ vertices. **This is the first of two points in the induction step at which the induction hypothesis is used;** the argument continues as follows.

If the contraction vertex $v_e$ were not in $Y$, then $Y$ would be an $A$-$B$ separator in $G$, so $v_e\in Y$. Let $X=\big(Y\setminus\{v_e\}\big)\cup\{x,y\}$; then $X$ is an $A$-$B$ separator in $G$. By hypothesis $|X|\ge k$; on the other hand, $|X|=|Y|+1$, and $|Y|<k$, so we must have $|X|=k$. We now have an $A$-$B$ separator with exactly $k$ vertices.

Now suppose that $S$ is an $A$-$X$ separator in $G-e$. Every $A$-$B$ path in $G$ must pass through $X$ and therefore through $S$, so $S$ is an $A$-$B$ separator in $G$; thus, $|S|\ge k$. $\|G-e\|=\|G\|-1<\|G\|$, so the conclusion of Menger’s theorem holds for $G-e$, which therefore has $k$ disjoint $A$-$X$ paths. **This is the second point in the induction step at which the induction hypothesis is used.** Similarly, $G-e$ has $k$ disjoint $X$-$B$ paths. If one of these $A$-$X$ paths met one of these $X$-$B$ paths outside of $X$, we could construct from them an $A$-$B$ path in $G$ that did not go through $X$, which is impossible, so the $A$-$X$ paths are disjoint from the $X$-$B$ paths outside of $X$. Being disjoint, the $A$-$X$ paths must terminate in distinct vertices of $X$. Similarly, each of the $X$-$B$ paths begins at a distinct vertex of $X$. Thus, each of the $k$ $A$-$X$ paths $\pi$ can be paired up with the $X$-$B$ path beginning at the terminal vertex of $\pi$ to make an $A$-$B$ path, and the $k$ $A$-$B$ paths formed in this way are disjoint. That completes the proof.

Comment: Thanks for answer! What if $x \in A$ and $y \in B$? Should it be mentioned as a spesial case, where Menger theorem still stands or does this proof include it?

Comment: @Ohto: You’re welcome! It’s not a problem: in that case $v_e$ belongs to both $A'$ and $B\,'$, but it’s still one of the vertices in $Y$, and the proof goes through unchanged.

Comment: Ok, I see :). 
Now I fail to see the contradiction. The structure of this proof keeps eluding me ... 
What things become contradictory and where does it take this proof? 
I also have hard time understanding, why the graph G-e is considered. Is it because contracting "$/$" eliminates vertices and deleting "$-$" eliminates edges?

Comment: @Ohto: There are a couple of sub-arguments that use proof by contradiction, but overall it’s not a proof by contradiction: it’s a proof by induction on the number of edges, and the induction step shows how the desired $A$-$B$ paths. It uses $G/e$ to show that $G$ has an $A$-$B$ separator $X$ with **exactly** $k$ vertices, and then it uses $G-e$ to show that there must be $k$ disjoint paths from $A$ to $X$ and $k$ from $X$ to $B$ that can be ‘sewn together’ to make $k$ disjoint paths from $A$ to $B$.