# I dont understand Mengers Theorem (graph theory)

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

I looked for a good proof for Mengers Theorem and there was a good one on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger%27s_theorem)
I understand the idea behind the proof but i stuck at some parts.
As far what i understand:
Its and induction over the edges. Its trivial if there are no edges.

1. Why are we able to asume by induction that it also applies for $G-e$ and
2. "If $G−e$ has a minimal $AB$-separator of size $k$, then there is an $AB$-connector of size $k$ in $G−e$, and hence in G. " ?

Now we define an $AB$-seperator S for $G-e$ with size less than k, otherwise  it would be a better seperator for G. Now it tries to build those $S_1$ and $S_2$ according the image on wikipedia.

3. Can someone explain me more detailed what happens from the point, where they define the $S_1$?

Thanks!

Comment: 1: Because it's induction on the number of edges. $G-e$ has fewer edges than $G$.

Comment: There are better proofs out there than the Wikipedia one. I suggest finding one in a graph theory book.

Comment: Yes, i read in a book that there are (atleast) 3 different approaches. This was one was the easiest in my opinion and at all articels which i have read, the one of wikipedia was the simplies to understand. Its just that those 2 , 3 steps are hard to understand for me. I liked the attached image.

Comment: Reinhard Diestel presents essentially the same proof in a slightly different way, and I expanded his presentation considerably in my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262165/induction-on-mengers-theorem-by-diestel-in-graph-theory) several years ago; see if you can follow that instead.

Comment: Thanks, this is surely a detailed explanation. The only think is the missing definition of a Seperator. I know what a seperator is supposed to be, but i really want to know what the exact definition is linked to this proof. Because if i read the definition on wikipedia, which states : " An AB-separator of size k is a set S of k vertices (which may intersect A and B) such that G−S contains no AB-path", doenst it already contain the theorem?